# ERROR No plugin found for prefix '.host.url=https' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am executing the below command to generate the sonarqube report for my maven java application-

`mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=<sonar-provided-projectKey>   -Dsonar.projectName='<Project Name>' -Dsonar.host.url=https://private-sonarqube.com -Dsonar.token=<private sonarqube provided token> -s jfrog-settings.xml`

`[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix '.host.url=https' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\bhargab3\.m2\repository), central-jfrog (https://navify.jfrog.io/artifactory/plugins-release), snapshots (https://navify.jfrog.io/artifactory/plugins-release), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]`

I tried adding the plugins in pom.xml suggested by other stackoverflow

Comment: What is your maven version?

Comment: Thanks for response. the command returns the below information- 



mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.9.6-bin\apache-maven-3.9.6
Java version: 17.0.9, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. run your command with -e, then post the stack trace.